# Boosting NFC range for mobile device

Tags: software, hardware, telephone, nfc

I am a type one diabetic and they just released a new advancement in technology. Its a sensor that transmits via NFC to your smart phone. But the range is one inch to be able to read the blood sugar. Is it possible to make a extender to pick up the nfc signals?

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Yes. Practical? Probably not.

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/154295/nfc-reader-long-range-antenna?rq=1) might shed some light on yours. You'd need a pretty big antenna coil if you wanted to transmit a longer distance than one inch. Definitely not a size that could fit inside a smartphone comfortably. I think it'd be better to just use Bluetooth if possible.

NFC transmits through such small distances for mainly security purposes, so you'd want data like blood-sugar levels to be especially secure.